# ASUS BIOS keeps resetting Boot priority to Windows Boot Manager before UEFI

Tags: boot, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, uefi

I have gone into F2 BIOS settings and saved

```
Boot Option #1    [UEFI: SanDisk]
Boot Option #2    [Windows Boot Manager]
```

[image]
However upon rebooting the system (Win10) goes straight to the hard disk Windows 10 installation without accessing the USB drive.

Here is screenshot that the BIOS has *automatically reset* to the Windows Boot Manager first again.

[image]
I had already tested this USB *on this same system* and it had booted in the past.  No idea why this new (and totally frustrating!) behavior is occurring.

Anyone else with knowledge/fix for this..

*Update*  I see this `Boot Override` in the `Save & Exit`.  It is not configurable. Is this relevant?   If so , how to remove the override?

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue on an Asus Z270-WS motherboard. I needed to disable all the devices except the one I wanted to boot from to be able to get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more digging found one answer here that is working.

http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1973164/change-asus-boot-order.html

I just completed a CHAT session with ASUS. It worked!! Here is what they told me:

> 1. Enter the BIOS setup menu by pressing and holding F2 key when powering on.
> 2. Switch to “Boot” and set “Launch CSM” to Enabled.
> 3. Switch to “Security” and set “Secure Boot Control” to Disabled.
> 4. Press F10 to save and exit.
> 5. Press and hold ESC key to launch boot menu when the Unit restarts.

We now get the following (happy!) screen:

[image]

And we can get to the Ubuntu Boot Disk:

[image]

(* 20 mins pass *)
And now I am logged in and editing this question from the (successfully) installed ubuntu 15.10  woot!

Comment: It might have worked for you, but be aware that enabling the CSM when a computer is already booting one OS in EFI mode is a recipe for creating problems. See [my Web page on this subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for details. If all you wanted to do was to boot the installation medium, you'd be better off looking for the computer's built-in boot manager. On my ASUS P8 H77-I motherboard, this is accessed by hitting F8 at startup.

Comment: This was a result of discussion directly with the vendor so it is a "blessed" approach.

Comment: Vendors, and especially first-tier customer support personnel, are often pretty clueless, particularly when it comes to dual-boot configurations. I maintain the [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) wrote the [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) partitioning software, and have direct personal experience with dozens of EFI-based computers, so I know much more about this than most manufacturer customer support personnel.

Comment: Ok, your position on this may well be solid. The vendor's approach worked in my case but as you point out it may not for others. I have only one instance to work from so can not further comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved this problem by DISABLEing the FAST BOOT option in te BOOT tab. And then all the disks are selectable further on that TAB

Comment: The person that asked the question already has that option disabled per the screen shot so how do you explain that your solution will work again?

Answer (score -1):

I tried disabling fast and secure boot but Windows still managed to put itself first.
It worked when I switched from Legacy/UEFI to UEFI only and there is also a Go2BIOS option in my boot options, which I also disabled.