# Bios Asus P8H67 doesn't remember boot order

Tags: boot, bios, multi-boot, uefi

Since a few days, my bios (Asus P8H67 ACPI BIOS Revision 3801) doesn't remember the boot order at startup so I get the following message:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
>
> or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key_

When going into the bios panel, I get that:

[image]

As you can see, the following default boot order is:

1- My SATA SSD Drive (Probably the legacy way)

2- Windows UEFI Partition on my SATA SSD Drive

3- Ubuntu UEFI Partition on my SATA SSD Drive

It seems like it is not able to boot from the SATA drive alone.

If I set Windows or Ubuntu as first, it will boot fine, but it will be back to default the next reboot...

I don't think the motherboard battery is at fault, since other bios settings are remembered correctly, and the clock time is correct. It really only forgets the boot order.

A fix I thought of was to switch the `PCI ROM Priority` from `Legacy ROM` to `EFI Compatible ROM`, but once this is changed, the bios doesn't boot at all, and gets stuck forever at the boot screen.

The BIOS firmware version is the latest on date.

I've seen an other topic about a similar situation, like this one:
[ASUS BIOS keeps resetting Boot priority to Windows Boot Manager before UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1043451/asus-bios-keeps-resetting-boot-priority-to-windows-boot-manager-before-uefi)
But the solution there seems to be enable/disable settings that I dont even have on my own BIOS (`Lunch CSM`, `Secure Boot Control`).

Is my motherboard fried, or is there a configuration that could work for good?

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: Maybe your CMOS battery is dead?

Comment: You have correctly set your disk as the first entry in "Boot Option Priorities". If you scroll the screen down, you should a section named "Boot Override", where you could maybe set your drive as the one to boot. Add a screenshot for us, please.

Comment: The CMOS battery is fine. I changed for a brand new one, and I still have the problem. I verified that the rtc reset jumper wasnt shortcircuiting the battery.
Afaik the Boot Override is valid for one boot only, so it is not a long term solution.
In the end I'm buying a new motherboard, this is just too annoying...
Thanks anyway guys!